# How to hook one module with other module in angular 2

Tags: angular, module, chaining

Suppose I have two modules "AppModule" & "EmployeeModule". And AppComponent.ts belongs to "AppModule" , EmployeeComponent.ts belongs to EmployeeModule.

I want to call EmployeeModule from AppModule, so that when opening the app I will see the content of both modules:

**Folder Structure in TypeScript:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akQ9Z.gif)

**AppComponent.ts:**

```html
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector:'app-root',
    template:`
              <h1>This is Root (AppComponent)</h1>
               
    `
})
export class AppComponent{}
```

**App.Module.ts**

```html
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import { EmployeeModule } from './Employee/employee.module';

@NgModule({
    imports:[BrowserModule,EmployeeModule],
    declarations:[AppComponent],
    bootstrap:[AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

**employee.component.ts**

```html
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector:'emp-root',
    template:`
              <h1>This is Root (Employee Component)</h1>
    `
})
export class EmployeeComponent{}
```

**employee.module.ts**

```html
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {EmployeeComponent} from './employee.component';
@NgModule({
    imports:[BrowserModule],
    declarations:[EmployeeComponent]
})
export class EmployeeModule{}
```

> I want to see the result like:

[Need to see this output]

[Fianal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJv8U.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Do change in this file:

**employee.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {EmployeeComponent} from './employee.component';
@NgModule({
    imports:[BrowserModule],
    declarations:[EmployeeComponent],
    exports: [EmployeeComponent], //export of the component that you will use in other module
})
export class EmployeeModule{}
```

**AppComponent.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector:'app-root',
    template:`
              <h1>This is Root (AppComponent)</h1>
              <emp-root></emp-root>
    `
})
export class AppComponent{}
```

[Working example in plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/e3kehHzTmecSzG2LJWcx?p=preview)